# Cleaning off packages installed via Terminal on OSX

Tags: macos, terminal

I have been learning to use Terminal to install packages (particularly to learn Ruby development). I believe that I'm experiencing some conflicts with things that have been installed and would like to remove them. The issue is, during my trial and error, forgot everything that was installed.

QUESTION:
Is there a way to list out anything that has been installed through Terminal? And what is the best way to remove those items? I assume they need to be uninstalled individually or I would have to a complete reset for OSX.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How exactly did you install packages?

Comment: At the time I was trying to get a number of tools installed for Ruby on Rails development, so Rails, HomeBrew, RVM and I also used the script here: https://github.com/monfresh/laptop

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for Homebrew but I would imagine the other utilities you used should have similar options. With Homebrew you can list everything installed by Homebrew with `brew list`. After this you can remove installed applications using `brew remove <application-name>`. Homebrew should have installed everything in `/usr/local/Cellar/`. I would recommend checking out the official [FAQ](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew) to learn how to uninstall Homebrew altogether. I know this doesn't cover all of the tools you used but I hope it helps at least a little bit.